# Java reflection: add final modifier to a class field

Tags: java, reflection

I'm looking for a way to make an object immutable dynamically by setting all properties of a POJO to be `final`. One way I thought of is to use Java Reflection to set the modifier to final.

Consider the following POJO:

```
public class Task {

   private String id;
   private String code;

   // getters and setters placed here

}
```

Using the above POJO example, I'd like to make `id` and `code` have a `final` modifier. By researching some examples on the internet, these examples refer to using bitwise operators to unset the final modifier.

e.g. the common line that does that is:

```
modField.setInt(idField, idField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
```

However, is there an example of setting the FINAL modifier to a field?
thanks.

Based on the comments below, I set the final modifier by using the following line

```
modifiersField.setInt(idField, idField.getModifiers() | Modifier.FINAL);
```

Then by writing a short piece of code to do a test to see if the modifiers change:

```
Field idField = c.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
System.out.println("Before = "+id.getModifiers());
id.setAccessible(true);
Field modField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
modField.setAccessible(true);
modField.setInt(id, id.getModifiers() | Modifier.FINAL);
idField.set(c, "DAVE");
modField.setAccessible(false);
idField.setAccessible(false);
Field f = c.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
System.out.println("After = "+f.getModifiers());
System.out.println("RES = "+c.geId());    //prints "DAVE"
```

So by checking this, I can see that the value certainly changes for the ID (i.e. to "DAVE"), but the modifier both before the change and after the modifier change is set to 2 (which according to the docs refers to modifier "PRIVATE" being set. Maybe based on other peoples comments it's not possible **see** a field having `final` set to it?

Comment: `idField.getModifiers() | Modifier.FINAL`?

Comment: This would only work for accesses of the field through the instance of `Field` that was modified. It won't affect direct code access or access through separate `Field` objects.

Comment: final is enforced by the compiler.  Adding it via reflection seems likely to have no value.

Comment: Thanks - i've just updated the question with more information

Comment: You can't change a field's modifier using reflection.

Comment: Too many variables in your example code, `idField`, `id`, `isoCodeField`, … how many `Field` objects do have, to address the same field?

Comment: I made an update on the code snippet. I think based on further investigation as well as comments from others it's not possible to change a modifier using reflection. thanks

Comment: It’s correct that you can’t make a field `final` this way, but at least, changing a simple `int` field like `modifiers` does work. Of course not, when the code doesn’t even pass the compiler, as you still have different variables `id` and `idField`. Why is it so hard, to just copy the actual code you used for your actual attempt (assuming that you did an actual attempt)? Besides that, when you do `idField.setAccessible(true);`, the subsequent `idField.set(c, "DAVE");` will succeed, regardless of whether the field is final or not.

Comment: can you explain why would you need that? But if nothing touched this class before you need to di it, you can use instrumentation api to change the class while its loading

Answer (score 0):

It is highly advisable to immediately change the .class instead of modify the loaded class. Especially for final constants. For this one can use a byte code manipulation library. The backdraw is the latest java version that the library can handle.

Final constants are special in that they are invisibly imported, copied to the immporting class. A huge disadvantage is that the compiler can no longer detects when the constant value in the original class is modified.

Making the fields final dynamically not optimize the code (as above, or in A+B), but rather only catch errors assigning from other classes.

You will have your valid reason. Assume you have `foo-1.2.jar`, creating `foo-const-1.2.jar`. Why not have `foo-const-1.2-src.zip` or such, and work with *final* refactored sources? Some code checkers (SonarLint?) detect exposed public fields as bad style.
So you can automate this, writing a script (say in java). But code checkers often also provide a refactoring out of the box.

- Let SonarLint run to detect which rule detects exposal of fields.
- Customize SonarLint/SonarCube for just that rule.
- Maybe you can per click refactor all fields.
- Otherwise collect those spots and write your own refactoring. Backing up the origina source.

You might even want to do a name refactoring converting fooBar into FOO_BAR.